# Storing the directory in a variable that a node.js script has been run from?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

If I run a node script in `C:\temp` in Windows how do I find out what directory that script is running from, (how do I find the path to where the script itself is located in the filesystem?)

The [fs module documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) doesn't seem to hold an answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[__dirname](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

process.cwd() will give you current working directory.

Comment: Apologies, but I down-voted this because it had an upvote and yet the OP specifically asked to know what directory the script is running in, which `__dirname` is guaranteed to do, and `process.cwd()` is not. And I guess my assumption (insert old joke here) is that the OP meant he wanted to know the directory of the script file itself.

Comment: @barry-johnson Yeah that was kind of a vague way of asking the question...but now we know the answer to two questions... :-p  Maybe it should be split into two questions and two answers.

Comment: I actually didn't think it was terribly vague myself. If you had asked where node was running from, as opposed to your script, I would have presumed you wanted the cwd. But yes, you are indeed now twice as informed. :-)

Comment: @Sociopath If you want credit for the other question, it's here to be answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213792/how-do-i-find-the-current-working-directory-of-a-node-js-program-to-store-in-a-v