# How do I find the current working directory of a node.js program to store in a variable?

Tags: node.js, filesystems, working-directory

I wish to store the directory my node.js script has been run from in a variable, how would I do this?

The [fs module documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) doesn't seem to hold an answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `__dirname`: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: Wrong!  See this other question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209709/storing-the-directory-in-a-variable-that-a-node-js-script-has-been-run-from?lq=1

Comment: @leeand00 Wrong what?